# As versões mais recentes (depois da versão 5.0.0 ) do entity framework core estão apresentando falha ao instalar no meu projeto. Este é um erro geral?

Tags: .net, nuget

Ao tentar instalar a versão mais recente do Entity Framework Core em um projeto, usando o Visual Studio 2019, via comando Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, me deparo com a seguinte resposta via console.

> Tentando coletar informações de dependências do pacote
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.3' em relação ao projeto
> 'ControleGeralFarmácia', visando '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2' A
> coleta de informações de dependência levou 0,2 ms Tentando resolver
> dependências do pacote 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.3' com
> DependencyBehavior 'Lowest' Resolver as informações de dependência
> levou 0 ms Resolvendo ações para instalar o pacote
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.3' Ações resolvidas para instalar o
> pacote 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.3' Recuperando o pacote
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.3' de 'Nuget'. Falha na instalação.
> Revertendo... O pacote 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.3' não
> existe no projeto 'ControleGeralFarmácia' O pacote
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.3' não existe na pasta
> 'C:\Users\asw\source\repos\ControleGeralFarmácia\packages' Executar
> ações do nuget levou 541 ms Install-Package : Não foi possível
> instalar o pacote 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.3'. Você está
> tentando instalar este pacote em um projeto  que se destina a
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', mas o pacote não contém nenhuma
> referência de assembly ou arquivo de conteúdo que seja  compatível com
> essa estrutura. Para obter mais informações, entre em contato com o
> autor do pacote. No linha:1 caractere:1
>
> - Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
>   ```

No entando quando tento instalar especificando qualquer versão igual o abaixo da 3.1.12, o pacote se instala sem mais problemas.

Comment: a mensagem parece bem clara: *"Você está tentando instalar este pacote em um projeto que se destina a '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2',"*  e nome do pacote é *"'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.5.0.3'"* tente instalar uma vesão compatível com o Framework que está usando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como explícito na mensagem, esta versão do `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` não é compatível com o framework usado no seu projeto. Neste caso vc tem 2 opções: usar outra versão; ou alterar o framework usado no seu projeto.

Sempre que for utilizar um package, convido-o a procurar saber mais sobre o mesmo, ler a documentação, saber quando e onde pode e deve ser usado.

Neste caso em concreto, visitando a página do pacote (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/5.0.3) é possível ver que esta versão é compatível somente com `NETStandard 2.1`.
[image: detalhes do Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.3]

Ao visitar a documentação do `NETStandard` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard), pode-se verificar que o .Net "Full" framework não implementa o `NETStandard 2.1`, não sendo, portanto, essa versão desde package compatível com o seu projeto.

**O que é o NETStandard?**

O `NETStandard` não é um framework, mas sim uma "especificação", podendo ser implementada por diversos frameworks. É preciso sempre verificar quais frameworks implementam quais versões do `NETStandard`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: @ClausembergRodriguesdeOlive caso a resposta tenha sido útil deverá marcá-la como aceita. [Como e porque aceitar uma resposta.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) [Como dizer obrigado em respostas.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/605/como-dizer-obrigado-em-respostas)